# convert string to list in Standard ML

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open file in ML(SMLNJ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168029/open-file-in-mlsmlnj)

I have a string value which has value like this:

```
"[(1,2,3),(2,3),(6,8)]" -> string
```

but I want to have these values in int type like this:

```
[(1,2,3),(2,3),(6,8)] ->   (int list) list
```

what should I do?is there any function which can help me? or I have to do it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is perfectly suited to parsing combinators, which you can [steal from my friend Greg Morrisett at Harvard](http://www.fas.harvard.edu/~lib153/hw/fish.zip).

If you want to understand the underlying ideas, read Graham Hutton's paper [*Higher-Order Functions for Parsing*](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/parsing.pdf).  If you want to know how to implement I/O in Standard ML, consult the [`TextIO` module](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/text-io.html) in the [Standard Basis Library](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/).  If you want someone to write the code for you, you may have reached the wrong web site.

Comment: This is probably not very helpful for him directly, but I agree with your answer. I was considering offering some advice; on rereading the explanation, I realized anything I said would fall on deaf ears, especially if I didn't provide the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringint` from the `String` module.
See for example http://wwwcgi.rdg.ac.uk:8081/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/wsi14/poplog/ml/help/string#Character%20Transformation%20Functions

Comment: it is like to using explode function in String but first it will give me string again. second I don't know what are i & j and those depends on entry.

Comment: Well, you have to split the input string by yourself, but this should be easy with `explode` and `implode`