# The usage of before in ML

Tags: sml, ml

ML's before is described in http://sml-family.org/Basis/general.html as

> a before b
>   returns a. It provides a notational shorthand for evaluating a, then b, before 
>   returning the value of a.

When I tried to use this command expecting x = 4 and (4+1) is evaluated

```
val x = (3+1 before 4+1)
```

I have the error message:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.78 [built: Sun Apr 26 01:06:11 2015]
- stdIn:1.11-1.25 Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload conflict]
  operator domain: [+ ty] * unit
  operand:         [+ ty] * [+ ty]
  in expression:
    (3 + 1 before 4 + 1)
-
```

What might be wrong?

### Edit

From Matt's answer, I should have used

```
val x = (3+1 before print "<end>")
```

I also found that `before` is used to close the stream after processing some FileIO functions.

```
(* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168029/open-file-in-mlsmlnj *)
val infile = "input.txt" ;

(*  reading from file follow this to list of string per line *)
fun readlist (infile : string) = let 
    val ins = TextIO.openIn infile 
    fun loop ins = 
     case TextIO.inputLine ins of 
            SOME line => line :: loop ins 
          | NONE      => [] 
in 
    loop ins before TextIO.closeIn ins 
end ;

val pureGraph =  readlist(infile);

size (hd pureGraph)
```

Comment: "and (4+1) is evaluated" Which effect did you expect the evaluation of `4+1` to have? Do you want the result to be printed or do you just want it to be calculated and thrown away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/Conversion/top-level-comparison.html), it says that the type of `before` is `before : ('a * unit) -> 'a`, and as your type error specifies, it is expecting the type of the second argument to be of type `unit`, however, you have supplied something of type `int`.  Try doing `val x = (3+1 before ())` and you should get the expected result.  The intended purpose is to have the second argument be some sort of side affecting computation, such as manipulating a `ref` cell or doing some IO, which you want to run prior to evaluating your first argument.  It seems that the following are the same:

```
val x = e1 before e2
```

and

```
val x = let val a = e1
            val _ = e2
        in a end
```

That said, `before` is not something I really use , so if anyone else has anything to add, comments are certainly welcome.

Comment: I have used it in situations where I want to get the old value of a counter before incrementing it.  !a before a := !a+1 .  There are a number of these in the Poly/ML compiler.